# rxjava2 producer-consumer, 'downstream' request one, the 'upstream' emit one

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I wanna using rxjava2 implement simple producer-consumer model, when downstream request one, and upstream emit one.

I know that `flatMap` or `observeOn` has default buffer size 128, so I set buffer size is 1, but it also not working.

```
Flowable.defer((Callable<Publisher<Integer>>) () -> Flowable.range(1, 5))
            .flatMap((Function<Integer, Publisher<Integer>>) integer -> {
                //do something with long time.
                System.out.println("flatMap:" + integer);
                return Flowable.just(integer);
            }, false, 1) //=====> 1
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 1) //=====> 2
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                    //request one
                    s.request(1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    System.out.println("onNext:" + integer);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Actual output:

```
flatMap:1
flatMap:2
onNext:1
flatMap:3
```

Expected output, because I call `s.request(1)` only one time:

```
flatMap:1
onNext:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observer only requests one item, but `observeOn()` will buffer one item as well. The `flatMap()` operator itself will subscribe to successive inputs.

1. Observer subscribes to observer chain, and requests 1 item.
2. `observeOn()` requests 1 item for its buffer.
3. `range()` operator emits 1.
4. `flatMap()` receives 1, and internally, subscribes to the flowable, causing the first log line.
5. `observeOn()` gets one item for its buffer, and then requests another item.
6. `flatMap()` gets the next item, 2. This is emitted and passed to `observeOn()` buffer
7. observer's `onNext()` is called.
8. `flatMap()` gets the next item, 3.

If you need perfect, lock-step, "request one" -> "process one", then flow-control is not the way to do it. Instead, you may want to introduce an observable that provides a feedback loop such that the observer tells the observable to process the next one.

Comment: Thanks for your detail steps. I also think `flowable` cannot  do that, so I will try your 'feed back loop' way.